# Scrollable tabs nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm doing an app using nativescript with the new tabs and i need at least 8, but i can not make this tabs scrollable, they appear piled up in the same view like this.

[my-tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZQRJ.png)

How can i make a scrolltab? I tried adding Scrollview with stack layout but my tabs crashed.

My code:

```html
<Tabs selectedIndex="0" swipeEnabled="true">
  <!-- Tabs -->
  <TabStrip>
    <TabStripItem>
      <Label text="Home"></Label>
    </TabStripItem>
    <TabStripItem class="special">
      <Label text="Account"></Label>
    </TabStripItem>
    <TabStripItem class="special">
      <Label text="Search"></Label>
    </TabStripItem>
    <TabStripItem class="special">
      <Label text="Search"></Label>
    </TabStripItem>
    <TabStripItem class="special">
      <Label text="Search"></Label>
    </TabStripItem>
    <TabStripItem class="special">
      <Label text="Search"></Label>
    </TabStripItem>
  </TabStrip>

  <!-- Contenido tabs -->
  <TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
      <Label text="Home Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
  </TabContentItem>
  <TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
      <Label text="Account Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
  </TabContentItem>
  <TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
      <Label text="Search Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
  </TabContentItem>
  <TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
      <Label text="Search Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
  </TabContentItem>
  <TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
      <Label text="Search Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
  </TabContentItem>
  <TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
      <Label text="Search Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
  </TabContentItem>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just resolve it, it only needs to put `iOSTabBarItemsAlignment="leading"` into Tabs element.